# Best way to use Javascript's "good parts"

Tags: javascript, abstraction

On Stackers' recommendation, I have been reading Crockford's excellent *Javascript: The Good Parts*.

It's a great book, but since so much of it is devoted to describing the best way to use Javascript's basic functionality, I'm not sure how I can put his advice into practice without duplicating the efforts of many other Javascript programmers.

Take this passage, for example:

> When you make a new object, you can select the object that should be its prototype. The mechanism that Javascript provides to do this is messy and complex, but it can be significantly simplified. We will add a `create` method to the `Object` function. The `create` method creates a new object that uses an old object as its prototype.
>
> ```
> if (typeof Object.create !== 'function') {
>  Object.create = function(o) {
>   var F = function () {};
>   F.prototype = o;
>   return new F();
> }
> ```

I could manually add this code to all my Javascript projects, but keeping track of everything would be a huge pain.

**Are there any libraries that implement *The Good Part*'s recommendations and thereby save me the trouble of having to keep track of them (/ physically type them all out)?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Prototype](http://prototypejs.org/) has many great features, including a [Class helper](http://prototypejs.org/api/class) that handles the details of JS "inheritance" via the object prototype.

Edit: damn, I keep forgetting that jQuery (my own library of choice) has [jQuery.extend](http://docs.jquery.com/Utilities/jQuery.extend)

Comment: `jQuery.extend()` copies attributes of the passed in objects into a target object. You cannot specify a prototype for the target object. IOW: It serves a different purpose than `Object.create()`.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't he work for Yahoo? You could always use the [Yahoo User Interface libraries](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/).

Personally, I'm partial to [JQuery](http://jquery.com/), as it strikes me as more concise, but you know: horses for courses.

Answer (score 1):

[Dojo](http://dojotoolkit.org) has followed Crockford's ideas very closely. For example, there is an implementation of the code snippet you have above implemented under the function `dojo.delegate` (in an even faster form).

I don't think there's a specific project that follow his recommendations to a tee. Most of the toolkits actually disagree with quite a few of his recommendations and patterns. If you're wondering about specific functionality, like that code snippet above, it would be worth asking about which specific tools from the book you want to use in your projects.

Answer (score 0):

I think YUI is the closest to what Crockford teaches in his book. (He's the Yahoo architect also and it makes sense)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [es5-shim](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim/), a library that provides an - albeit incomplete - shim for `Object.create()` and other things.